# getting the highest number out of a SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine i had a set of **30 records**
for instance

> `users : {user_id, name, category}`

and i did this Query:

```
     SELECT name
     FROM users
     WHERE category = "Student"
     AND id < 30
     ORDER BY user_id
     LIMIT 5
```

This would give me the users that have id from 1 to 5
but how about if i wanted to get the highest id values that are less than 30
in this case the desired results would be id's from 24 -29.

ps. my real problem is a bit more complex than this, i just wanted get the basic theory.
also note that i would of used another AND clause to say > 23, but this wouldnt work with my schema.

Comment: `ORDER BY user_id DESC` would help?

Comment: @JohnWoo he can also achieve this by formatting the limit too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap what Dan J wrote into a set and SELECT from it, then applying an ASC order.  Not sure of the MySQL syntax, but in MS SQL it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (Dan J's code) a
ORDER BY user_id [ASC]
```

The ASC is optional.

Comment: true!  Detail I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the results of the same query in descending order:

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE category = "Student"
AND id < 30
ORDER BY user_id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This will return the largest five IDs. Though it might be worth elaborating on what you're actually trying to accomplish. There's something a little fishy about sorting by an ID column. :)

Comment: I tried descending values, but it won't with the way im doing things, the tables need be ordered in ascending.

Comment: for instance say the DB returns 29 columuns, can't we say get the highest id numbers from them and then order them in an ascending order?

Comment: How about wrapping what Dan J wrote and SELECTING from that in ascending order?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE category = "Student"
AND id < 30
ORDER BY user_id 
LIMIT 25,5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a sub-query:

```
     SELECT name
     FROM users
     WHERE category = "Student" AND
         id >((SELECT MAX(id) FROM users)-5) AS temp
     ORDER BY user_id
     LIMIT 5
```

Depending upon your table structure, you could move `category = "Student"` to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a logic like this?
[* On SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbb20/22)

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT quiz_name
    FROM cursos
    WHERE id < (select max(id) from cursos)
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT 5) ) tbl 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

It takes MAX row ID from your table and get highest 5 ID values. E.g. MAX = 9, it gives you 8, 7, 6, 5, 4. *Editted:* After adding ASC outer select order, you get it as 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.

PS: Ignore my table schema, it was an old one I just used for this example.

**Editted version:** - sorry my net was down.

You should indeed use that nested SELECT wrap mentioned by Sebt. However you need to include ID within the nested select, so you can select it from the tbl outer select query.